# Alert when input is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an alert (once) when the input is clicked. Here is my attempt so far.

```js
$("#target" ).focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .select() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_text" id="target">
```

What should I do to fix it

Comment: Fix your post title first...

Comment: Your question is about `once` or what?!

Comment: Remove `id="input_text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two **`id's`** for input also you can use **`.click`**

**DEMO**

```js
$("#input_text").click(function(){
  alert( "Handler for .select() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click','#input_text',function(){
  alert('Clicked me :)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The input tag has two ids, id="input_text" maybe type="text"?
And when the input is focused,it will be always focused,so use click event,it will be better.

```js
$("#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .select() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="target">
```